# Access script from another script not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to access a function, with a bool parameter, from one script to another and just can't get it to work. I have been looking around to try to understand what i am doing wrong.

Here is the script i am calling:

```
public class MainScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public void ManageBoxCollider2D (bool shouldColliderBeEnabled) {
        print (">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>ManageBoxCollider2D: " + shouldColliderBeEnabled);
    }

}
```

I am trying to call it from this script:

```
public class Sidebar1_Script : MainScript {
    public MainScript mainScript;

    void Start () {
         mainScript.ManageBoxCollider2D (true);
    }
}
```

*There is a lot of other stuff in the scripts as well but this is what matters for this question*

In the "Sidebar1_Script" I am trying to access "ManageBoxCollider2D" in "MainScript" but it does not work.

I do get the following message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

...which i do understand but can't figure out what i am doing wrong.

I would appreciate some help how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to drag/drop your script int inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because unity doesn't know what script that is. If you see in the inspector you're gonna find that public variable `MainScript` is still empty, also you can't assign scripts in the inspector (I don't know why though, when you drag it there it won't fit in).

Instead change your `Sidebar1_Script` like this:

```
public GameObject obj;

void Start () {
    MainScript main = obj.gameObject.GetComponent<MainScript>();
    main.ManageBoxCollider2D(true);
}
```

And then assign the game object of `obj` in the inspector (drag the game object to the public variable).